# Scala Automatic creation of functions in setter

Tags: scala

I am trying to learn scala. So a very basic question i need to understand.

```
class learnGetterSetter {
  var size = 1
}

val f = new learnGetterSetter
f.size_=(10)
println("Printing after setting value: " + f.size)
```

I can see in above example size_= function is automatically created for variable size to set any value. I can think of inheritance somewhere in the background but i could not understand from where exactly is the function size-= coming from?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Compiler autogenerates getters and setters for any ```var``` inside a ```class``` They don't come from any parent class. Both subtyping and the use of variables are discouraged in Scala

Comment: Note that if you make the variable private then the setter won't be created. Also, usually you would call that setter as `f.size = 10`